# Is there any Possibility to reset the partitions after installation

Tags: partitioning

I installed Ubuntu 16 on a 8GB pendrive (Bootable Drive) and created two partitions for Ubuntu(Ext4 - 6000MB, Swap - 2000MB). I want to resize the partitions without re-installing the Ubuntu. Is there any possibility???

Comment: It's possible to change sizes, move partitions, delete swap, but reset, no, I don't think so. May very much depend on your definition of reset.

Comment: What does **reset** mean?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If by `reset` you mean `resize` then there's a utility called `gParted` which can be used but it will destroy the data as any kind of change in partition table of drive will end in formatting that part of drive.

Therefore, No, there isn't any possibility.

Comment: partitions can be resized without destroying data

Comment: @ravery How can I do that

Comment: with gparted. boot from a LiveCD

Comment: https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual